# Cannot perform unwind segue on selecting search result - the navigation stack will not be updated

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I have two view controllers, the first one(VC1) has a button and when click on that it will navigate to the second view controller(VC2). VC2 is a table view includes a list of names and it has search bar on top for searching. If I select a cell normally, it will call to unwind segue to pop back to VC1. However, if I search for a name, and then on the search result, I select a cell, it cannot perform that unwind segue, it just dismisses the search UI and result an error like this:

> popToViewController:transition: called on UINavigationController while
>   an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation
>   stack will not be updated.

I also try to dismiss the VC2 on tableview:didSelectCellAtIndex but no use.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following function:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: You should delete your pop function in code,because you made it in the storyboard

Comment: I connect the tableview cell with unwind segue in the storyboard, so there is no pop function in code, however, it cannot work.

Comment: You must have done this----'popToViewController:transition:'.It warned you.Search your code.

Comment: It works perfectly now follow your code, I finally delete my unwind segue in storyboard and just call to "popViewControllerAnimated:" in "tableview:didSelectCellAtIndex". Thank you so much Lumialxk!

Comment: You do not need to disconnect your unwind segue in storyboard.  Add this if check to "prepareForSegue:" instead:

  if (self.searchController.isActive) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }